using ignorant as a positive word
"ignorant" simply means "unaware" 
Like when I say he is ignorant of the facts, it means that he is not aware of the facts. But in general, the word ignorant has taken up "stupid" as its prominent meaning. It is even considered negative and negative only.
When I want to say someone doesn't know how to lie, in a literary piece, I would prefer putting it as,

ignorant of uttering lies

But I am a bit wary of using this phrase fearing it might give a negative connotation to it.
What do you all think about the usage to mean something positive like in the example quoted above?

No, it won't work, partly for the reason you give, but also because it means unaware of some information - it doesn't get used of a capability or incapability.

I am seeing "how to lie" as the information. Wouldn't it work?

In that case it would have to be 'ignorant of how to lie', but, as Colin says, we don't use ignorant for inability to do something.

You could use "ignorant" to imply innocence, particularly of something negative.
Sally arrived from her hometown ignorant of the wicked ways of the Big City but she was a quick study.

so going by that would you say "ignorant of separation" "ignorant of uttering lies" are all acceptable?

Acceptable, but "ignorant of uttering lies" is not clear and a bit strange. Is the person ignorant that lies were being uttered, or is she ignorant of how to lie convincingly?

hmm I see the problem. Thanks.
